# AJAX function always return html code in response on success

Tags: ajax, laravel

In laravel 5.8 project I am trying to use JQuery AJAX function to send a get request to one of project routes url the status of response is 200 which means that the request executed successfully but every time the function return the current view HTML in response

I tried to remove all the code in my php function and return only a JSON response but still getting HTML I also tried to change data type to JSON or text and setting cache to false but the response still the same I even tried to comment all the function the route requesting and the same response always come out 
I also tried many other solutions offered here or on other sites but no way to solve it

Here is my controller function that the route requesting:

```
public function seen()
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    $notifications = $user->notification;
    foreach($notifications as $notification){
        $notification->seen = 1;
        $notification->save();
    }

    return response()->json(['status' => 'seen']);
}
```

Here is the function route:

```
Route::get('/seen', 'CustomAuth\AuthController@seen')->middleware('authUser');
```

And finally the AJAX function:

```
    function seen(){
        let url = '/seen';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Response I get when i set contenType to text:

[image: Response Headers]

I expect that I would get a JSON response that I am try to return within the function but I suppose that the request do not reach the function and the problem is within the ajax request

Comment: Try to add  echo json_encode($data); in PHP and in jquery try Datatype:json

Comment: I had a similar issue, forcing headers (specifically content-type to txt) helped.

Comment: I am getting an object that contains response attributes    ````{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}```` @NiketJoshi

Comment: @KareemSaeed can you show a print out of response and request headers?

Comment: You could also try returning plain json rather than response()->json();, I'm quite sure there's a helper function to turn any array into json.

Comment: I updated the question you can check the response headers @JCode

Comment: do you have a method named `notification` in your `User` model, to call it like this `$user->notification`, if its correct then, please show me the code of that method

Comment: Yes there is a notification function in user model ````public function notification()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Notification');
    }```` @ShridharSharma

Comment: @KareemSaeed Have you tried as I've suggested, returning a plain json without response()->json() ?

Comment: Can you explain how I can do this? @JCode

Comment: Can you show me the full response you're getting, because I think there's some error from server side, therefore Laravel is serving the error HTML page

Comment: No the HTML code return in response is for the current page I try to send the request within @ShridharSharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the middleware from your response.

Comment: Still getting HTML in response after trying your function.   I do not think that the problem is related to the route if it is web or api as I used to do it the same way I am doing now to add a web route and it was working very well

Comment: @KareemSaeed How are you printing the data in the screenshot? Are you simply doing console.log(data)?

Comment: console log the response in AJAX success function ````success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }````

Comment: @KareemSaeed I know it's a wild shot, but could you replace 'data' with 'result'? - yes, I mean the parameter name.

Comment: Ok I changed the parameter to 'result' but still nothing changes

Comment: @KareemSaeed what jQuery version are you using? My console.log(result) returns json string and json string only, no 'responseText' etc.

Comment: jQuery version 3.1.0

Comment: I've just tested your code in my project and it works flawlessly, so I'm guessing the issue comes from your middleware. @KareemSaeed

Comment: @KareemSaeed try removing `->middleware(*)`.

Comment: Yes this was the problem I updated an answer to the question, many thanks for your help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function seen(){
    let url = '/seen';   $.ajax({
    url: "getusersallapp",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
       '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
    },
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

As JCode suggested the problem was within the middleware added to the route.
As if case in the middleware returns false the middleware redirects to the current page so it returns the page HTML code in AJAX response

Comment: I've editted my answer so if anyone stumbles upon it knows what the cause might be.